# Soldering station - sensor fault protection

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, soldering

I have got the attached soldering station schematic and I need a protection for the soldering iron heater in case of disconnecting one or both thermocouple wires. 
Source of the schematic: http://electronics.vlzqz.com/home/lm324-analog-soldering-station

1. I added the Rx1 (100k) resistor to the thermocouple amplifier block. Will this resistor protect the soldering iron by blocking the triac in case of disconnecting one or both thermocouple wires?
2. During the testing of the schematic I saw that if I use MOC3041, the led flashes at a higher frequency in comparison to MOC3021. Which one, between MOC3041 and 3021 should I use?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Use of the LM324 for a thermocouple first-stage is risky. It has up to 7 mV of input offset at room temperature.

Comment: Like... 7mV / 50uV = 140 degrees of temperature error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is sensor-open protection in the form of that 100K resistor. The current is unnecessarily high so you will get excessive error due to the resistance. All you have to do is overcome the leakage current of the capacitor at some tens of mV, so it could probably be 10M if you use a ceramic 10uF capacitor. Note that the bias current for this particular op-amp flows out of the inputs. I would use a 1uF or 10uF ceramic, move it to the non-inverting input and reduce the 10K to 1K ohms.

You don't have protection against a short (eg. thermocouple shorted away from the junction, between the leads or to ground), but that's relatively difficult to do without a microcontroller or a second sensor.

As far as the MOC3xxx goes, the zero crossing MOC3041 is not designed for 24V use, so it will reduce the maximum power somewhat.

The op-amp has a typical drift in the 5uV/°C range, a large offset and the circuit has no cold-junction compensation so you'll get an unknown offset to begin with and the tip temperature will drift upward about 1:1 with the temperature at the connections 1 & 2. In other words if those connections heat by 20°C your tip temperature might go from 340°C to 360°C.

Comment: I modified the schematic: https://ibb.co/cCqVJRK . It is correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You could go one order of magnitude further and reduce the two 1K to 100 ohms and reduce the 100K to 10K.

Comment: I can't find 1uF ceramic (in my capacitor box), is there an alternative ? It is possible to use polypropylene capacitor ?

Comment: PP capacitor would be better actually.

Comment: I found some PP capacitors, but MKT capacitor fits better on the PCB (in terms of dimensions). It is possible to use MKT capacitor ?

Comment: I believe MKT is polyester film so okay. But you can check the type.

Comment: I checked the type of capacitor. It is polyester film. For testing the thermocouple protection, should I only disconnect the wires and see if the U1C is having 0V on the output ?

Comment: Disconnecting either lead or both should turn the heater off.

Comment: If I go one order of magnitude further by replacing 1K to 100 ohms and 100K to 10K, then the capacitor should remain at 1uF ?

Comment: The value is not particularly critical. 1uF is fine. It's just to keep EMI out of the front end. If it's  too low, EMI gets in. If it's too high the response time gets slowed, but that's nowhere near an issue.